# Why am I getting undefined index for a column that exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying a DB but for reasons unbeknownst to me I keep getting undefined index.

The Undefined index it's referring to IS in the DB and everything IS spelld correctly. (I've checked & re-checked) yet still undefined index.

As part of my diagnosis I changed it from `$variable['index']` to `$ariable['index']` and I get an undefined variable so I know the variable works.

Additionally, I am selecting `*` in the query behind $variable yet I'm still getting the undefined index.

If anyone could set me straight on what's happening I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting a php error or a mysql error?  Please post some code

Comment: Could you provide some code? We aren' t that good with guessing :)

Comment: Can you post a copy of the code your using?

Comment: @TimothyChoi That's the first-use-then-investigate function in php :D (unless your working with circular objects of course)

Comment: You may try to restart/ recreate database. Sometimes it runs into different bugs, and you have to recreate it. Once I've had a bug, that it said that `table doesn't exist`, but I couldn't create it(because of `such table already exists`)

Comment: I'll try to get some code up soon

Comment: @PHPlover Also good for variable analysis.

Comment: @Stuart Kaufman My guess is that you're fetching the data as a numeric array instead of associative array

Comment: table names are case insensitive, fieldnames are case-sensitive

Comment: Some blind guesses are (1) not fetching a result row and trying to index into the result resource, or (2) fetching a row with `mysql_fetch_row` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. In either case, `print_r($variable)` or `var_dump($variable)` will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

index is a  [**reserved**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) word in MySQL. If an identifier contains  a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it.